# Unable to send GPS coordinates to server

Tags: java, android, apache, gps

I am trying to send GPS coordinates to server got by my app,it is showing GPS coordinates correctly, but unable to send it to server, the problem is in my MainActivity.java
Here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

  private TextView latituteField;
  private TextView longitudeField;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private String provider;
  int lat,lng;


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_location);
      latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
      longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

      // Get the location manager
      locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
      // default
      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
      provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
      Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

      // Initialize the location fields
      if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
      } else {
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
      }
    }

  /* Request updates at startup */
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }



  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
      lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
      latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
      longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));



    }



  @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

  @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

  @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  private class LoadServerASYNC extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
      }

    void postData() {
      // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://182.18.144.140:80"); //your php file path

      try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "1.0256"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", "1.0256"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I am not getting what is the problem

Comment: Maybe you should check LogCat stacktrace?

Comment: The problem is, you are not executing the asyncTask(LoadServerASYNC).

Comment: @amitsingh can you please tell me, how to do it?

Comment: @user3209703 are you still stuck in that problem?

Comment: @amitsingh ya i am still strucking in problem

Comment: @user3209703 show your updated code for this class

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing and executing the LoadServerAsync anywhere.

If you want to send coordinates every time  you update the text views, you should do this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    LoadServerASYNC task = new LoadServerASYNC();
    task.execute();
   }
```

And you should call postData method inside doInBackground();

Comment: I followed your post, but still i am not getting any response from server side. I need server to return string